# Java get first 2 decimal digits of a double

Tags: java, math, double

I have a huge double that i want to get the first 2 decimal digits as float from. Here is an example:

```
double x = 0.36843871
float y = magicFunction(x)
print(y)
```

Output: `36`

If you don't understand feel free to ask questions.

Comment: show the `magicFunction` implementation

Comment: do you need 'only' first 2 numbers and store it as a float (or) from your example do you need your output as 36.843871 ??

Comment: I need a float output without and decimal digits.

Comment: 0.36843871 is not a huge double. The actual range of the double does however make a huge difference to the answer, so you need to provide it, or say whether it's unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could multiply by `100` and use [`Math.floor(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) like

```
int y = (int) Math.floor(x * 100);
System.out.println(y);
```

I get (the requested)

```
36
```

Note that if you use `float`, then you would get `36.0`.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for. Thanks :D

Comment: If x is greater than 1, you will get an answer with more than 2-digit.

Comment: `x % 1d * 100` if greater than 1

Comment: You don't need `Math.floor()` at all here. The integer cast does it all.

Comment: Why `Math.floor` or integer cast rather than `Math.rint`? Try testing this code with x equal to 0.29.

Answer (score 3):

You could multiply `x` by 100 and use `int` instead of float. I tried the below code:

```
double x = 0.36843871;
int y = (int)(x*100);
System.out.println(y);
```

And got output as:

```
36
```

Answer (score 2):

In case x is greater than 1 and negative:

```
    double x = -31.2232;
    double xAbs = Math.abs( x );
    String answer = "";
    if( ( int )xAbs == 0 ) {
        answer = "00";   
    }
    else {
        int xLog10 = ( int )Math.log10( xAbs );
        double point0 = xAbs / Math.pow( 10, xLog10 + 1 ); // to 0.xx format
        answer = "" + ( int )( point0  * 100 );   
    }
    System.out.println( answer );
```

Comment: Returns 36. First two digits are 23.

Comment: And now, what exactly is the point of multiplying zero by 100?

Answer (score 2):

To handle the negative case and all ranges correctly:

```
double y = Math.abs(x);
while (y < 100)
    y *= 10;
while (y > 100)
    y /= 10;
return (float)(int)y;
```

You also need to handle zero correctly, not shown.